# MySQL <class '_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError'>, OperationalError(1148, 'The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version')

Tags: mysql

I am getting a strange error from my SQL when trying to insert a file into mysql on aws RDS.

```
(<class '_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError'>, OperationalError(1148, 'The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version'), <traceback object at 0x7f34d8485dd0>)
```

I am running on ubuntu 12.04 desktop and just did a apt_install mysql-server mysql-client.

How can I resolve this?

mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.24, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Comment: As a note...I went back to 11.04 and the same code base worked.  Clearly there is an issue with the apt-get package for 12.04.  I have yet try to install from source.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the mysql server with --local-infile=1

So depending on how you start your server it would look like:

**$ mysql --local-infile=1 -u root -p**